# how to pass variable from custom module to its tpl

Tags: drupal

I need to know the simplest method to pass variable from custom module to its template
I have created the custom.module and placed custom.tpl.php in the module folder

```
function custom_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['custom'] = array(
    'title' => t('custom!'),
    'page callback' => 'custom_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_page() {

    $setVar = 'this is custom module';
    return theme('custom', $setVar);    
}
```

i have added theme function but it is not working, can any one suggest me what is wrong with this code

```
function theme_custom($arg) {
  return $arg['output'];
}

function custom_theme() {
  return array(
    'Bluemarine' => array(
        'variables' => 'output',
        'template' => 'Bluemarine',
     ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function custom_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['custom'] = array(
    'title' => t('custom!'),
    'page callback' => 'custom_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_page() {
    $result = db_query('SELECT * from node');
    return theme('custom', array('output' => $result));
}

function custom_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom' => array(
      'arguments' => array('output' => NULL),
      'template' => 'custom',
     ),
  );
}

function template_preprocess_custom(&$variables) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the wrong theme function. Instead of `function theme_custom` it should be `function theme_Bluemarine`. You also need to pass an array to the variables piece of [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).  See a simple example [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7#comment-14989).

Using your example:

```
function custom_menu(){
  $items = array();

  $items['custom'] = array(
    'title' => t('custom!'),
    'page callback' => 'custom_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_page() {
  $setVar = 'this is custom module';
  return theme('custom', array('output' => $setVar));
}

function custom_theme() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom');
  return array(
    'custom' => array(
        'variables' => array('output' => null),
        'template' => 'custom',
     ),
  );
}
```

Now in custom.tpl.php just need `<?php print $output; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

First, you've to declare you theme and how its behave with the help of [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7). After you can easily use the function theme.

Also, maybe you will need to use the [hook_preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7).

Comment: Thanks for reply, i m using Bluemarine theme. can you post the sample code with respect to the code which i posted above? plz help

Comment: dear yvan i didn't really understand ur reply plz elaborate that how can i pass variable to custom theme thanks